# How can I copy/paste the *formatting* of a table in Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm wondering if there's a feature in ppt 2010 to paste the formatting of one table onto another (e.g. table borders, cell background colour). I've tried all the paste specials but nothing seems to work.

It would seem really strange to me if this feature doesn't exist (you can paste formatting of other objects easily), so does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: For some reason, in PowerPoint, using Format Painter or pasting will only change text formatting, not boarders or backgrounds.

Comment: Indeed, my problem exactly :-) Anybody has an idea on how to copy/paste borders & backgrounds?

Comment: Will require custom coding in VBA with two procedures, one to read and save the formats from the "copy" table and another to apply the formats to the "paste" table. Not truly difficult code, but a bit tedious given the number of format properties for a table, some applying to the table as a whole, a lot of others cell-specific.

Comment: Year 2020: still impossible to copy-past a formatted table in PowerPoint inside the same presentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, what you are asking for is not possible.

If all your tables are to have the same style, you could [create a presentation template](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-a-powerpoint-template-ee4429ad-2a74-4100-82f7-50f8169c8aca) that has this one style as default table style.

Another option is to copy the table out of PowerPoint into some other Office application such as Word or Excel that is more flexible, then copy it back.

Comment: I'm afraid your link is no longer valid and I can't think what it should now point to.

Comment: @MSC: Link replaced by another.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just copy the whole slide and then delete the text that you don't want.  That way you have an identically formatted table to work off of.

Comment: This is the only viable option on here because all I wanted to do was clone the slide.

Comment: But not really viable when I already have tables on several slides and want to change style (especially column widths) of all of them in one go... or at least apply to each table individually, but without dealing with individual style property or individual column property...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in PowerPoint 2010, a good tutorial is found [Here](http://www.powerpointninja.com/powerpoint-2010/powerpoint-2010-paste-options-%E2%80%93-love-at-first-sight/).  The power point ninja explains how to save the source formatting and not lose your colors and and cell formatting.

Comment: Invalid: The tutorial does not apply to tables.

Comment: Just tried it myself, and it works.  You have to select "Keep Source Formatting".

Comment: You treat the case of copying a table. The question is about copying the **total format** of a table by Format Painter or other means.

Answer (score 0):

Not really in the manner you have asked.

If you have a corporate style that you need to use for all templates, what you would really like if for that style to appear on the ribbon in Table Tools -> Design -> Table Styles so you can just click and apply your formatting.  The only way to make this easy is for someone to delve into XML and VB  to make it happen.  See [this post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-you-create-custom-table-styles-t3674886.html) for more information and an example.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I follow every time I need to deal with this issue (unfortunately in PowerPoint 2010 the Format Painter do not copy the background or borders) is the following:

I copy the entire table from PowerPoint to Excel in order I can adjust the styles, change the border properties, the background, and make all the changes I need to do to the table.

When I am done, then I copy the table back to PowerPoint. Make sure you paste it in the right way (see paste special options). If you don't need to change the number of cells then the best way to paste it is highlighting the existing cells (select all the table cells) and then paste the content from Excel inside your PowerPoint table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copy tables to Excel, manipulate them and copy back the result to powerpoint.